# spark with yarn connection exception

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I was trying to execute the following commands for the first time :

```
    YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop 
    spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

It is throwing the following connection exception:

> java.net.ConnectException: Call From styne-Lenovo-ideapad-520-15IKB/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I tried to add following in yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
<value>false</value>
```

and also i tried this :

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
<value>5</value>
```

Both these didn't solve the problem. How to resolve the issue.

Comment: did you check if hadoop/yarn is running?

Comment: No. How to do that ?

Comment: By refering this https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused i tried : telnet localhost 9000 and it is giving Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: you should start hadoop first and then check if hadoop is running or not just by doing jps in the terminal

Comment: you are correct. Once I started hadoop it is working.

Comment: what does mean of hadoop start? which compenent of hadoop?